# Почему возникает ошибка syntax error, unexpected '('?

Tags: php

Есть такой вызов:

`return DataHelper::createFullnameFormatter()($this);`

Но интерпретатор упорно ругается на потерянную скобку (именно на этой строке где вызов):

syntax error, unexpected '('

Я все раз 100 пересмотрел - ну нет нигде потерянной скобки. Это моя реализация нескольких несложных хелперов, основанных на замыканиях:

```
/**
 * @param string $format
 * @param array ...$attributes
 * @return \Closure
 */
public static function createFormatter($format, ...$attributes) {
    return function($model) use($format, $attributes) {
        $args = self::toArray($model, $attributes);
        return vsprintf($format, $args);
    };
}

/**
 * @return \Closure
 */
public static function createFullnameFormatter() {
    return self::createFormatter('%s %s %s', 'lastname', 'firstname', 'middlename');
}

/**
 * @param Model|array|object $model
 * @param array $attributes
 * @return array
 */
public static function toArray($model, $attributes = []) {
    if ($model instanceof Model)
        $model = $model->attributes;
    elseif (is_object($model))
        $model = get_object_vars($model);
    elseif (!is_array($model))
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('$model must be instance of "%s", array or object!', Model::className()));

    $selector = function($key) use($attributes) {
        return in_array($key, $attributes);
    };

    return $attributes ? array_filter($model, $selector, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY) : $model;
}
```

При этом когда я вызываю так:

`return call_user_func(DataHelper::createFullnameFormatter(), $this);`

работает без ошибок. Но так вызывать длиннее и менее читабельно. Мне бы хотелось разобраться почему не работает первый вариант? Это что опять проблема синтаксиса? Пхп не поддерживает такое?

Comment: Чему вы пытаетесь передать `$this`? Классу? Тогда, насколько я знаю, нужно писать так: `return DataHelper($this)::createFullnameFormatter();`. И добавьте полностью код вашего класса `DataHelper`

Comment: @Klimenkomud Функции возвращаемой createFullnameFormatter. И это весь код DataHelper который относится к делу. Все что там еще есть не затрагивается вызовом.

Comment: @Klimenkomud Но это весь ее код. :( Функция называется getFullname и просто возвращает полное имя текущего объекта.

Comment: Переходите на php7, там вызов `DataHelper::createFullnameFormatter()($this);` будет отрабатываться верно. В php5 делать так: `$name = DataHelper::createFullnameFormatter(); return $name($this);`.

Comment: @Visman Жаль. В который раз разочаровываюсь в этом языке. Мне это уже надоело. :( К сожалению в современных реалиях не так то просто переходить на новый пхп. Просто тупо есть уже масса сайтов которые написаны на старых версиях (на том же сервере) и если сменить версию пхп то они сломаются.

Comment: Язык развивается. Старые сайты придется обновлять до новых версий php. Это и повышение скорости работы. И безопасность.

Comment: Статистика использования версий php на текущий момент https://seld.be/notes/php-versions-stats-2017-2-edition

Comment: @DarkByte вы же в курсе, что можно использовать разные версии PHP для разных сайтов?

Comment: @PavelMayorov на одном и том же сервере? Нет, не в курсе. Как это возможно? Наверное сложно настроить...

Comment: @DarkByte https://serverfault.com/a/279360

Comment: @PavelMayorov Это лишь установка пакетов (кстати у меня на сервере CentOS, а не убунта), но надо ведь еще сделать чтобы конкретные сайты юзали конкретную версию.

Comment: @DarkByte так растащите их на разные пулы php-fpm. Вообще говоря, это стоит сделать даже если они на одной версии.

Comment: @PavelMayorov не знаю что это такое :(